# code suddenly stops working with flask and zenora (Discord oauth2)

Tags: python, flask, oauth, discord

when i went to restart my code because i have made changes to the index.html file and no chages to python i get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
from server import server
File "/home/runner/HangoutNet-Bot-Web/server.py", line 13, in <module>
client = APIClient(OAUTH_TOKEN, client_secret = OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET)
File "/home/runner/HangoutNet-Bot-Web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zenora/client.py", line 57, in __init__
self._validate_token()
File "/home/runner/HangoutNet-Bot-Web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zenora/client.py", line 61, in _validate_token
self.users.get_current_user()
File "/home/runner/HangoutNet-Bot-Web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zenora/impl/userapi.py", line 55, in get_current_user
payload = Request.make_request(self._token, url, "GET")
File "/home/runner/HangoutNet-Bot-Web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zenora/request.py", line 83, in make_request
return req.execute()
File "/home/runner/HangoutNet-Bot-Web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zenora/request.py", line 74, in execute
return raise_error_or_return(r)  # type: ignore[return-value]
File "/home/runner/HangoutNet-Bot-Web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zenora/errors.py", line 49, in raise_error_or_return
for x in json_data["errors"]:
KeyError: 'errors'
```

i am running my code on replit
https://pastebin.com/PE9x71Fx

it was working fine before

Comment: Fix 
reinstall using replit.com packages tab

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to import this from zenora:

```
from zenora import BadTokenError
```

next you will need to add a try statement to your route like this for an example:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    try:
        if "token" in session:
            bearer_client = APIClient(session.get("token"), bearer=True)
            current_user = bearer_client.users.get_current_user()
            return render_template("index.html", current_user=current_user)
        return render_template("index.html")
    except BadTokenError:
        return redirect(OAUTH_AUTH_URL)
```

Hope This helps you!
What you needed to do was redirect them back to the oauth url to re validate their token since it was invalid.